# SystemJS with Typescript conflict?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I am trying to configure SystemJS for an existing AngularJS + Typescript application.

I have a problem with module loading: 
When I use this syntax:

`import module1 from './path-to-module1'`

TS compiler is happy but SystemJS will not find this module. After a little investigation I found [this](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#defaultjsextensions), on SystemJS documentation:

```
System.defaultJSExtensions = true;

// requests ./some/module.js instead
System.import('./some/module');
```

Cool, now both TS compiler and SystemJS work. But, SystemJS documentations says:

> Note that this is a compatibility property for transitioning to using explicit extensions and will be deprecated in future.

So, I figured out that I should add a `.js` extention to my module loading, like this (removing the 'defaultJSExtensions = true' flag):

`import module1 from './path-to-module1.js'`

Now SystemJS knows how to load my module, by TS compiler says:

`Cannot find module './path-to-module1.js'`

How can I make TS figure this out? Should I manually add all my modules to a `*.d.ts` file? How?

10x!

**EDIT**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30735904/916450), which I guess should be what I need to do. I found this on my Grunt file:

```
typescript: {
      build: {
        src: ...,
        outDir: '...',
        reference: 'reference.ts',
        options: {
          target: 'es5',
          sourceMap: false,
          declaration: false,
          removeComments: false,
          experimentalDecorators: true,
          module: 'commonjs'
        }
      }
    }
```

But, changing the `commonjs` to `system` did not help hree..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, the SystemJS documentation is a bit misleading... Once they remove the defaultJSExtension all you have to do it to mark your code directory as a package (In the systemJS configuration) You can read about it [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/759)

Anyway, the file name without the extension is a valid ES6 module [import syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), so SystemJS will have to support it, as I said they will support it using a different way in the configuration.