# Error: (SystemJS) require is not defined in Angular 2

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am relatively new to Angular and I am trying to build a MEAN app using Angular2, NodeJs, Express and MongoDB. I have been following a tutorial which is a little old, so some of the instructions were out of date. 
So I used the quick start guide from Angular to set it up.

In my index.html file I have the following line `System.import('app').then (null, console.error.bind(console));` resulting in `Error: (SystemJS) require is not defined`

The code below if from my systemjs.config.js file.

```
    System.import('app').then (null, console.error.bind(console));`
which gives me the error `Error: (SystemJS) require is not defined`. 
The problem is inside the systemjs/index.js file, as I am using this in the nodemodules on the front end. 

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for a couple of days now, and people suggest that I use a bundle or an import statement, but I am unsure about the syntax I need to use. 
Here is the code that is giving me the issue:
if (typeof Promise === 'undefined')
  require('when/es6-shim/Promise');

var version = require('./package.json').version;

var isWindows = typeof process.platform != 'undefined' && process.platform.match(/^win/);

// set transpiler paths in Node
var nodeResolver = typeof process != 'undefined' && typeof require != 'undefined' && require.resolve;
function configNodePath(loader, module, nodeModule, wildcard) {
  if (loader.paths[module])
    return;

  var ext = wildcard ? '/package.json' : '';
  try {
    var match = nodeResolver(nodeModule + ext).replace(/\\/g, '/');
  }
  catch(e) {}

  if (match)
    loader.paths[module] = 'file://' + (isWindows ? '/' : '') + match.substr(0, match.length - ext.length) + (wildcard ? '/*.js' : '');
}

var SystemJSLoader = require('./dist/system.src').constructor;

// standard class extend SystemJSLoader to SystemJSNodeLoader
function SystemJSNodeLoader() {
  SystemJSLoader.call(this);

  if (nodeResolver) {
    configNodePath(this, 'traceur', 'traceur/bin/traceur.js');
    configNodePath(this, 'traceur-runtime', 'traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js');
    configNodePath(this, 'babel', 'babel-core/browser.js');
    configNodePath(this, 'babel/external-helpers', 'babel-core/external-helpers.js');
    configNodePath(this, 'babel-runtime/*', 'babel-runtime', true);
  }
}
SystemJSNodeLoader.prototype = Object.create(SystemJSLoader.prototype);
SystemJSNodeLoader.prototype.constructor = SystemJSNodeLoader;

var System = new SystemJSNodeLoader();

System.version = version + ' Node';

if (typeof global != 'undefined')
  global.System = global.SystemJS = System;

module.exports = System;
```

I have tried updating my npm, typescript and even angular-cli. I have also changed the 'module' in my tsconfig.app.json file and added `format: 'register'` to my systemjs.config.js file.

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep rolling back my changes where I separate your actual question from the code blocks?  Either way, SystemJs doesn't use `require`, it uses `import`.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860461/2495283, for example, for the differences between require and import.

Comment: You had deleted some of the lines where I write the error I am getting. 
That's what I though as well, but unfortunately in the file it's using require and I don't know how to change it into imports. It would be great if you could point me to the right syntax and how to change them.